# Copy multiple range selection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with some code I found on Google. I'm trying to copy data on multiple sheets, and paste it into a summary sheet.

I'd like to copy the data in A23 and in H8:S8 onto the blank lines on the summary sheet. `A23` would be in column `A` and `H8:S23` would be in columns `H` through `S`.

Here is what I have, although its not working.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With


    ' Set Summary Worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tab_Upload")

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(Left(sh.Name, 1)) = "_" Then

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
            Last = ActiveSheet.[a65536].End(xlUp).Row

            ' Specify the range to place the data.
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("H8:S8, A23")


            ' This statement copies values and formats from each
            ' worksheet.
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With



        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried setting it up and I'm getting a "That command cannot be used on multiple selections" when I just manually select and attempt to copy two ranges. However, if the two or more ranges are the same size, no problem. I imagine it's because they're different sizes VBA doesn't handle those nicely. Try doing them one by one. I put an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting it up and I'm getting a "That command cannot be used on multiple selections" when I just manually select and attempt to copy two ranges. However, if the two or more ranges **have the same number of columns**, no problem. I imagine it's because they're different sizes VBA doesn't handle those nicely. Try doing them one by one, like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DoStuff()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim summary As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> summary.Name Then
        ws.Range("A1").Copy summary.Range("A" & summary.Range("A" &    summary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        ws.Range("C1:D4").Copy summary.Range("A" & summary.Range("A" & summary.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Edited, if you copy multiple ranges, they have to have the same number of columns

Comment: It worked! I just added an offset to the second ws.Range and that aligned everything nicely. Thank you!